# Unable to install rbenv correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

I've followed the installation instructions for rbenv:
https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/

However, the shims are not being used, for instance, when running `bundle` it attempts to use the binary located in `/usr/local/bin/bundle` rather than in the `/.rbenv/` directory (and fails). It complains that my Ruby version should be 1.9.2 or higher - but it is!

Running `rbenv rehash` seems to do nothing.

Comment: Are you sure you are in the right directory? Do you have configure file in your current directory?

Comment: No! :) Which directory should I be in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow "For example, to install Ruby 1.9.2-p290, download and unpack the source, then run"?

You got to visit [Ruby website](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) and download the ruby version you want to install. After downloading, extract the archive and change directory to the extracted archive and then run the command

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194
```

That should work.

Comment: I see, I didn't realize that command was to move Ruby to the /versions/ folder. (Makes sense now!). However I used `ruby-build` to do that. So I guess that command isn't the problem.